# Running an exact phrase match against all fields under multiple indexes in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to run an exact phrase match against all the fields under multiple indices.

The elastic java api has a method `matchPhaseQuery`

```
/**
     * Creates a text query with type "PHRASE" for the provided field name and text.
     *
     * @param name The field name.
     * @param text The query text (to be analyzed).
     */
    public static MatchQueryBuilder matchPhraseQuery(String name, Object text) {
        return new MatchQueryBuilder(name, text).type(MatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE);
    }
```

The problem is it requires the field names to run a match phrase query against. 
Whereas I need to run against all the fields under multiple indices.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In match phase query method the field name will

> "_all"

```
matchPhraseQuery("_all", Object text){}
```